# Unable to select timeline in connection view for Network Profiler

Tags: android, profiler

I am trying to monitor my application's network activities using network profiler with Android studio 3.3.2, I can see and select profiler timeline range for an android emulator with API level 28. Along with I can see activities for Android Device with API level 23 but I can not select a timeline to check the connection and thread view for the mobile device. Any heads up on this. How can I select the timeline range to view the connection and thread view for the mobile device?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

To show you advanced profiling data when running a device with Android 7.1 or lower, Android Studio must inject monitoring logic into your compiled app.

To enable advanced profiling, follow these steps:

1.Select Run > Edit Configurations.
   2.Select your app module in the left pane.
   3.Click the Profiling tab, and then check Enable advanced profiling.
   4.Build and run your app again.

[image]